# SOAP SW-SECURITY SIGNATURE BINARY_TOKEN AND TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, soap, digital-signature, xml-signature

hello i am developing a service for a SOAP call with x509 authentication and i need to sign the body and timestamp, but i can't get it to work java side while in SoapUI it does.

The error (with java code) is SSF_API_SIGNER_ERORS A signing opration not be performed or failed

the configuration in soapUi is this

[image]

while my signature code is this

```
      private void createDetachedSignature(SOAPElement signatureElement, PrivateKey privateKey, SOAPElement securityTokenReference, SOAPBody soapBody, SOAPElement timestamp) throws Exception {
        
        
            String providerName = System.getProperty
                    ("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");
            XMLSignatureFactory xmlSignatureFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM",
                    (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());
        
        
            //Digest method
            javax.xml.crypto.dsig.DigestMethod digestMethod = xmlSignatureFactory.newDigestMethod("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1", null);
            ArrayList<Transform> transformList = new ArrayList<Transform>();
        
        
            //Transform
            Transform envTransform = xmlSignatureFactory.newTransform("http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#", (TransformParameterSpec) null);
            transformList.add(envTransform);
        
        
            //References
        
            ArrayList<Reference> refList = new ArrayList<Reference>();
            Reference refTS = xmlSignatureFactory.newReference("#TS"+UUID, digestMethod, transformList, null, null);
            Reference refBody = xmlSignatureFactory.newReference("#Body"+UUID, digestMethod, transformList, null, null);
        
        
            refList.add(refBody);
            refList.add(refTS);
        
        
            javax.xml.crypto.dsig.CanonicalizationMethod cm = xmlSignatureFactory.newCanonicalizationMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#",
                    (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null);
        
            javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignatureMethod sm = xmlSignatureFactory.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1", null);
            SignedInfo signedInfo = xmlSignatureFactory.newSignedInfo(cm, sm, refList);
        
            signatureElement.setAttribute("Id", "SIG" + UUID);
        
            DOMSignContext signContext = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, signatureElement);
            signContext.setDefaultNamespacePrefix("ds");
            signContext.putNamespacePrefix("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "ds");
        
        
            //These are required for new Java versions
            signContext.setIdAttributeNS
                    (soapBody,
                            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "Id");
        
        
            signContext.setIdAttributeNS
                    (timestamp,
                            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "Id");
        
        
            KeyInfoFactory keyFactory = KeyInfoFactory.getInstance();
            DOMStructure domKeyInfo = new DOMStructure(securityTokenReference);
            javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo keyInfo = keyFactory.newKeyInfo(java.util.Collections.singletonList(domKeyInfo));
            if (securityTokenReference instanceof Element) {
                Element keyInfoElement = (Element) securityTokenReference;
                keyInfoElement.setAttribute("Id", "KI" + UUID);
            }
            javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature signature = xmlSignatureFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo);
            signContext.setBaseURI("");
        
        
            signature.sign(signContext);
            String signatureValue = getSignatureValueAsString(signatureElement);
            System.out.println("Signature Value: " + signatureValue);
        
        
            Element canonicalizationMethodElement = (Element) signatureElement.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "CanonicalizationMethod").item(0);
            addInclusiveNamespaces(canonicalizationMethodElement, "soapenv urn");
        
            NodeList referenceNodes = signatureElement.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "Reference");
            for (int i = 0; i < referenceNodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element referenceElement = (Element) referenceNodes.item(i);
                Element transformsElement = (Element) referenceElement.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "Transforms").item(0);
                Element transformElement = (Element) transformsElement.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "Transform").item(0);
        
                addInclusiveNamespaces(transformElement, "wsse soapenv urn");
            }
        
        
        }
```

I tried to compare the two requests and now I attach them to you

SOAP UI REQUEST

```
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
        <soapenv:Header>
            <wsse:Security
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
                    EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
                    ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
                    wsu:Id="X509-8C92EF6DC231D5F4321700816423308691">
                    MIIIEjCCBfqgAwIBAgITHQAAZ/wkXidRhqKJ2wADAABn/DANBgkqhkiG...........</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-8C92EF6DC231D5F4321700816423307690">
                    <wsu:Created>2023-11-24T09:00:23Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>2024-02-15T17:00:23Z</wsu:Expires>
                </wsu:Timestamp>
                <ds:Signature Id="SIG-8C92EF6DC231D5F4321700816423348695"
                    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soapenv urn"
                                xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                        <ds:Reference URI="#TS-8C92EF6DC231D5F4321700816423307690">
                            <ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse soapenv urn"
                                        xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                                </ds:Transform>
                            </ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                            <ds:DigestValue>7KhZ1yTPuNhQ7OtTn32HcJQQ04U=</ds:DigestValue>
                        </ds:Reference>
                        <ds:Reference URI="#id-8C92EF6DC231D5F4321700816423308694">
                            <ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList=""
                                        xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                                </ds:Transform>
                            </ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                            <ds:DigestValue>t5f22r+WwrehIN/rbI7EFwLq7tM=</ds:DigestValue>
                        </ds:Reference>
                    </ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:SignatureValue>
                        KRttsmdFmqCRQyTmo6/Cgs1Vj8EZ1y9YbObETjtcvhNQUBRny7tIKZE3bH4TwR69L2x0MsosaAcefeuT/OkowAa............</ds:SignatureValue>
                    <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-8C92EF6DC231D5F4321700816423308692">
                        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-8C92EF6DC231D5F4321700816423308693">
                            <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-8C92EF6DC231D5F4321700816423308691"
                                ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
                        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                </ds:Signature>
            </wsse:Security>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-8C92EF6DC231D5F4321700816423308694"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <urn:SCHEMA_CC>
                <IV_BP>3960915933</IV_BP>
            </urn:SCHEMA_CC>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

My request java

```
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
            <soapenv:Header>
                <wsse:Security
                    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                    Id="SIG-1B1352404FC17AFA99AD1B962FA2A67E">
                    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1B1352404FC17AFA99AD1B962FA2A67E">
                        <wsu:Created>2023-11-24T08:18:32Z</wsu:Created>
                        <wsu:Expires>2023-11-24T08:19:02Z</wsu:Expires>
                    </wsu:Timestamp>
                    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
                        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
                        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
                        wsu:Id="X509Token-1B1352404FC17AFA99AD1B962FA2A67E">
                        MIIIEjCCBfqgAwIBAgITHQAAZ/wkXidRhqKJ2wADAABn..........</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
                    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                                    PrefixList="soapenv urn" />
                            </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                            <ds:Reference URI="#Body-1B1352404FC17AFA99AD1B962FA2A67E">
                                <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces
                                            xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                                            PrefixList="wsse soapenv urn" />
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                </ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                                <ds:DigestValue>qOQ+Nv9QAe63RePMKZkCfn2a8xI=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                            <ds:Reference URI="#TS-1B1352404FC17AFA99AD1B962FA2A67E">
                                <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces
                                            xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                                            PrefixList="wsse soapenv urn" />
                                    </ds:Transform>
                                </ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                                <ds:DigestValue>grbt4GpvYhKKUaetcW2HHMm91Mw=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                        </ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:SignatureValue>agesPe4aOZPE9m1aI17MDz+oE5V7YNk7ox6q1WvmHWjd7EdH4XdqVq62dMnqkE2RRbI5TafX1qnK&#13;
                            udGLnMFcZu/gIYMUYmZ1RrwO6y39tLDWii8hEIZMYj/jIzAqi6d1jXh8GOjtmflYnIsRnidFgokV&#13;
                            /fgoMn7c548QlvEPyCokgFlS/aF4OF5uKqnb/yJ2ilRbeJBlG9QCO5rEUGmgeZ0untABzP+w76yg&#13;
                            PTkPaDTC8UHDQsG4XWMTYL+dyGfnHpYdqz5v+4BI53KfG0V7eqbdCZj9dzYN2MEel1NrgqQP2uQ8&#13;
                            .........</ds:SignatureValue>
                        <ds:KeyInfo>
                            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference Id="KI-1B1352404FC17AFA99AD1B962FA2A67E"
                                wsu:Id="STR-1B1352404FC17AFA99AD1B962FA2A67E">
                                <wsse:Reference URI="#X509Token-1B1352404FC17AFA99AD1B962FA2A67E"
                                    ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
                            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
                    </ds:Signature>
                </wsse:Security>
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                wsu:Id="Body-1B1352404FC17AFA99AD1B962FA2A67E">
                <urn:GET_SCHEMA_CC xmlns:urn="http://www.example.com/urn">
                        <IV_BP>3960915933</IV_BP>
                
                </urn:GET_SCHEMA_CC>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The way to put the certificate in the securityBinaryToken seems correct to me, while the signature I don't know if it is the correct way to do it.